# Reactjs - Yup : How to check if 2 inputs are equal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

Im having a error when I try to use oneof frin yup

error message(`enums.forEach is not a function`).

My fields code :

```
    {...}
{({ isSubmitting }) => (
            <Form>
              <TextInput
                name="password"
                type="password"
                label="Senha"
                placeholder="***********"
                icon={<FiMail />}
              />
              <TextInput
                name="confirmpassword"
                type="password"
                label="Confirme a senha"
                placeholder="*******"
                icon={<FiLock />}
              />             
            {...}
```

My validation code :

```
{...}
 validationSchema={ 
            Yup.object({
              password: Yup.string()
                .min(8, "senha é muito curta")
                .max(30, "senha é muito longa")               
                .required("O campo senha não pode ser vazio"),
              confirmpassword: Yup.string()
                .min(8, "senha é muito curta")
                .max(30, "senha é muito longa")
                .oneOf('password','senhas devem combinar')
                .required("O campo senha não pode ser vazio"),
            })
          }
{...}
```

I want to validate if a field is equal the other ,someone knows how to fix it ?

Comment: @SoufianeBoutahlil yes it does , thanks for your patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In yup I cant handle the equality error with this code :

```
FIELD: Yup.string().oneOf([Yup.ref('password'), null],'MESSAGE THAT YOU WANT TO APPEAR').min(8, 'Error')
```

thanks to `@SoufianeBoutahlil` and this link
[password validation with yup and formik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49502436/password-validation-with-yup-and-formik)